# What is verbose in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

Can anyone explain me what is `verbose` in rails?

```
ActiveRestClient Verbose Log:
Request
>> POST /URL
>> Accept: application/json
> Body : Requst
```

I see `verbose true` in my models, what does that imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't related directly to Rails but instead with a gem you have installed: https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client

See https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client#debugging for details including:

> You can turn on verbose debugging to see what is sent to the API server and what is returned in one of these two ways:

[snip]

> By default verbose logging isn't enabled, so it's up to the developer to enable it (and remember to disable it afterwards). It does use debug level logging, so it shouldn't fill up a correctly configured production server anyway.